# Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

The same thing is asked like 1000 times but I have CommonModule Injected.

I have a lazy-loaded module and used on multiple routes like inside the main layout and outside of it

It works perfectly but when I run tests cases in it, they keep throwing `Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'` even though I have injected common module and ViewChild is also returning undefined if it's inside ngIf or even if it's not the ViewChild just returns the start end tag of the component called.

HTML of the in question module ( Test Module )

```
<ng-container *ngIf="step === 'search'">
  <app-search #search></app-search>
<ng-container>
<app-unsaved #unsaved></app-unsaved>
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('unsaved') unsaved: UnsavedComponent;
@ViewChild('search') search: SearchComponent;
```

Routing

In main layout

```
{
    path: 'test',
    canActivate: [ValidatedGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('@app/test.module').then(mod => mod.TestModule)
},
```

In lazy loaded routing

```
{ path: '', component: TestComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }
```

Everything looks and it works fine but when I run the tests cases,

```
WARN LOG: 'Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.'
```

and

```
ElementRef{nativeElement: <app-unsaved></app-unsaved>}



@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        TestComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        TestRouting,
        CommonModule,
        SearchModule,
        QuotesModule,
        ConfirmModule,
        UnsavedModule
    ]
})

export class TestModule { }


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: TestComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }
];

export const TestRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

Comment: Have you done `import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'`?

Comment: Can you add the NgModule definition of `TestModule` please ?

Comment: @RobBailey yes read first line

Comment: @cyr_x hey edited now

Comment: hate angular !! i somehow removed declatations from spec file, after adding that everything worked

Comment: My issue was using `ng-if` instead of `ngIf`, lol (adding this for fellow n00b googlers)

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally show something with `ng-container` use `*ngTemplateOutlet` attribute.

The value you give it should be template reference of an element and do a ternary operator if you want to show it or not.

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="step === 'search' ? appSearch : null">
<ng-container>

<ng-template #appSearch><app-search #search></app-search></ng-template>
```

Comment: hey appreciate that but step is initiated with 'search' in constructor and it throws no errors when i use the application in the browser, it' only unit tests with karma says ngIf is not binding

Comment: Ah, than i cant help because i am not familiar that much with karma tests.